# what does applicationId means in ms-graph 'create' subscription response

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Following response is received when creating a microsoft graph subscription    .
what does this **applicationId** means. is it static value ?.

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#subscriptions/$entity",
  "id": "7f105c7d-2dc5-4530-97cd-4e7ae6534c07",
  "resource": "me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",
  "applicationId": "24d3b144-21ae-4080-943f-7067b395b913",
  "changeType": "created,updated",
  "clientState": "secretClientValue",
  "notificationUrl": "https://webhook.azurewebsites.net/api/send/myNotifyClient",
  "expirationDateTime": "2016-11-20T18:23:45.9356913Z",
  "creatorId": "8ee44408-0679-472c-bc2a-692812af3437"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it imply, it is client id where you register app.When you list the all subscriptions , api only returns subscriptions that are created by specific client (application).
i have confused subscription application id's which were created using  [graph explore](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) and my app